# Why does the MLE of the uniform distribution not satisfy a Central Limit Theorem?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

For $X ~ U(0,\theta$)

The MLE of $\theta = \max{x_i}$.
Why does this not satisfy $\sqrt{n*I(\theta)} *( \max(x_i) - \theta) -> Z $
Where Z has a normal distribution?

I understand that $\max{x_i} < \theta$ which would make the bracketed term negative but I don't think this is the answer. Also, the sequence of estimators is consistent.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why should it? The CLT applies to a sum of random variables...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distribution of extremal values is seldom normally distributed. The maximum of a bounded random variable will converge to a [Type 3 Extreme Value Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theory)  (call ed *weibull-law* in the link).

At the more basic level, the curvature of the log-likelihood at the extreme value is undefined, hence it will not converge to a quadratic log-likelihood.

Comment: Thank you, I need to prove this technically using the fact that the MLE is < $\theta$, so do I need to use the score function for the derivative of the log-likelihood?

Comment: @KateSinclair yes, show that the score function fails to become linear as $n\to\infty$

Comment: The score function is $ n/ \theta * I(0<max(xi)<\theta)$ ...which is still linear?

Comment: @KateSinclair dont forget that the score function is a function of $\theta$ not $x_i$

Comment: @KateSinclair no matter how large you make $n$, your likelihood will be monotonic, hence it will not become quadratic. That's all you need to show.

Comment: Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: "At the more basic level, the curvature of the log-likelihood at the extreme value is undefined, hence it will not converge to a quadratic log-likelihood." This is an excellent example of *scare* mathematics.